# Submitting form to database error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add a simple form data to a mysql databse and it seems to not work.

It gives me this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in portfolio-add-website.php on line 7

and portfolio-add-website.php looks like this:

```
<?php
include 'connect_db.php';

$connect = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DB);

mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO portfolio_websites 
                       (name, link, description, profile_img_name, 
                        cover_img_name, client_name, donedate) 
                VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[link]', 
                        '$_POST[description]', 
                        '$_POST[profile_img_name]', 
                        '$_POST[cover_img_name]', '$_POST[client_name]', 
                        '$_POST[donedate]')";
?>
```

I don't see any unexpected ";". Can anyone help me? I'm sure it's something small.

Comment: your paranthesis and quotation marks are somewhere in wrong order. The first opening paranthesis is at least not closed. But the quotation marks are somewhere wrong as well (I don't know the expected syntax, so can't give more detailed hint)

Comment: you just missed out the last brackets

Comment: add `)` to last line before `;`

Comment: add `)` to the line between `";` i.e `");`

Comment: @razvan You got answer or not ?

Answer (score 2):

You missed  a closing brace

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO portfolio_websites (name, link, description, profile_img_name, cover_img_name, client_name, donedate) 
VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[link]', '$_POST[description]', '$_POST[profile_img_name]', '$_POST[cover_img_name]', '$_POST[client_name]', '$_POST[donedate]')");
```